# Is there anyway to do something in all exception cases in pl sql?

Tags: exception, plsql

I want to assign a value to a variable when exception occurs.

```
exception
  when excep1 then
    var = true;
  when excep2 then
    var = true;
end;
```

I want to do something like, Is it possible?

```
exception
   var = true;
   when excep1 then
    -- do something
   when excep2 then
    -- do something
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-raising as Odi suggested would definitely work.  You get the same effect by doing things a little differently.

```
begin
  var := true;

  ... your code that can cause exceptions...

  var := false; --var set to false unless an exception was encountered
exception
  when exception1 then
    ...
  when exception2 then
    ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks John, it's really great.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a sub-block, first set the value and then re-raise the exception to handle it:

```
  begin
    begin
    -- do something
    exception
      when others then
        var = true;
        raise; -- re-raise the current exception for further exception handling
    end;
  exception
    when excep1 then
      -- do something
    when excep2 then
      -- do something
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Odi :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to put it in another procedure, e.g.:

```
declare
  procedure common_exception_routine is
  begin
    var = true;
  end common_exception_routine;
begin
  ...
exception
  when excep1 then
    common_exception_routine;
  when excep2 then
    common_exception_routine;
end;
```